# JavaScript Set Window selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, selection

In JavaScript, there is a method `window.getSelection()`, that lets me get the current selection that the user has made.

Is there a corresponding function, something like `window.setSelection()`, that will let me set, or clear, the current selection?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but maybe you can just focus the user's text
$('someselector').focus(function(){$(this).val('');}); 
This will select user's text, thats what you meant?

Comment: @Shaked KO This question is about the selection on the page, like when you click and drag over some text.

Comment: I'm gonna put it out there - I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @Ed yes it is, at least in some browsers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe this will do it:

```
window.selection.clear();
```

Crossbrowser version:

```
if (window.getSelection) {
   if (window.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome
     window.getSelection().empty();
   } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox
     window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
   }
} else if (document.selection) {  // IE?
  document.selection.empty();
}
```

Comment: Chrome supports `removeAllRanges()`, so you don't need the extra branch. Downvote removed, although `window.selection.clear();` is still useless (and will throw an error) and the rest is essentially a copy of part of my answer.

Comment: @Tim, fair enough .. except for the part about the copying of your answer. 

It appears by looking at the time the answers were posted that your answer is the one that is a copy of what I posted. The 'copy' generally comes after the original.

Comment: I suggest you check the times again. Regardless, I'm not bothered so long as the accepted answer is correct, and all correct answers to this question are going to look essentially the same.

Comment: @TimDown - Weird. I see my answer posted at 15:51, your posted at 16:10. (shrug).

Comment: This only clears the selection. Tim Down's answer also restores it.

Answer (score 21):

Clearing the selection in all major browsers:

```
function clearSelection() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        document.selection.empty();
    }
}
```

Selecting content requires use of [DOM `Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:range) and [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:selection) objects in most browsers and [`TextRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) objects in IE < 9. Here's a simple cross-browser example that selects the contents of a particular element:

```
function selectElement(element) {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (document.selection) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(element);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> NOTE: This is an experimental technology
> Check the [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/removeAllRanges#browser_compatibility) table carefully before using this in production.

**Clear Selection:**

```js
// get a Selection object representing the range of text selected by the user or the current position of the caret.
var selection = window.getSelection();
selection.removeAllRanges();
```

**Set Selection By Node:**

```js
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = document.createRange();
    
range.selectNode(nodeToSelect);

selection.addRange(range);
```

**Set Selection By Indexes:**

```js
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = document.createRange();
    
range.setStart(nodeToSelect, this.startIndex);
range.setEnd(nodeToSelect, this.endIndex);
    
selection.addRange(range);
```

**Get Current Selection**

```js
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In browsers that support the "selection" and "range" stuff, you'll want to create a range object and then set its start/end.  The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range) for the "range" object has a lot of information.

<strike>Chrome doesn't support this, at least not with that API, and I bet Safari doesn't either.</strike>

*edit* — thanks to @Tim Down for noting that WebKit (Chrome & Safari) do indeed support this, which means my jsfiddle had a typo or something!

Comment: WebKit does have support for Range and Selection.

Comment: @Tim Down - really?  When I tried it in Chrome I got an error from `document.createRange()` (to the effect that there was no such function).  I'll try again.

Comment: @Tim Down hmm well I must have just had a typo or something ... I'll edit the answer.  Thanks!!