# Chrome execCommand returns error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, getelementbyid, execcommand, dom

How do I use the execCommand() in Chrome? Here is the code I have right now
It is being used to insert a special character when hitting the tab button

```
function editAble(supr){
    document.getElementById('codeline').contentEditable='true';
    document.getElementById('codeline').onkeydown=function(e)
        {

        if(e.keyCode==9){
            e.preventDefault();
            range1 = document.getElementById('codeline');
            range1.execCommand("InsertHtml",false,"p");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `execCommand()` method is a method of `Document` objects, not elements. IE also provides `execCommand()` as a method of its `TextRange` and `ControlRange` objects, but these are not present in other browsers.

```
document.execCommand("InsertHtml", false, "p");
```

You may want to consider what happens if the user presses the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key when the user has previously selected some text: in that case you'd probably want to [delete the contents of the selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190143/javascript-set-window-selection/6190426#6190426) before inserting your tab character.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I just have 0 idea how to approach it correctly. I feel like what I have should work, but it just... doesn't. Also, in every other browser but chrome, if I have the contentEditable area set to a pre, than the Tabs work without JavaScript