# Obtaining a DOM Range by clicking anywhere within an Element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, kendo-ui, range

Given the following HTML...

```
<p>Today is <span data-token="DateTime.DayOfWeek">$$DayOfWeek$$</span>,
</p>
<p>Tomorrow is the next day, etc, etc....</p>
```

Clicking on $$DayOfWeek$$ returns a [DOM Range](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html) object (via a component, which is a [WYSIWIG editor bundled with KendoUI](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/editor#methods-selectedHtml)).

I can then access the entire Element like so...

```
var element = range.startContainer.parentElement;
console.log(element);
```

which outputs...

```
<span data-token="DateTime.DayOfWeek">$$DayOfWeek$$</span>
```

What i am trying to figure out is how to construct a Range object that consists of the entire Element, as a Range.

The desired 'high level' behaviour is to single click a piece of text, and have the browser select all the text within that element, returning a Range object.

Happy to accept a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<p>Today is <span data-token="DateTime.DayOfWeek">$$DayOfWeek$$</span>,</p>
<p>Tomorrow is the next day, etc, etc....</p>
```

JS

```
var span = document.querySelector('[data-token]');

span.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    range.setStart(span.childNodes[0], 0);                      
    range.setEnd(span.childNodes[0], span.innerText.length);
    sel.addRange(range);                      
});
```

Here's a fiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/V66zH/2/

It' might not be super cross browser, but works in chrome. See [JavaScript Set Window selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190143/javascript-set-window-selection) for some additional optimizations elsewhere.

Also assumes only one childNode as in your example html

Some additional reference for Ranges (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range) and Selections (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Was really easy to adapt your fiddle into the editor component and simply pass it the created range to enable the selection of the whole element.

Comment: in FireFox i get an error at span.innerText ... so i changed the jsFiddle a bit ..

    `var TX = span.textContent || span.innerText;
    range.setEnd(span.childNodes[0], TX.length);`

.. and this way i think it works in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

here is a way i came up with that seems to work if i understand you correctly, that you want the element surrounding a click to produce a range containing everything in that element.

without the onclick code, which i assume you can handle, here is the DOM range code you describe:

```
var sel=document.getSelection(); //find the node that was clicked
var rng=sel.getRangeAt();  //get a range on that node

//now, extend the start and end range to the whole element:
rng.setStart(rng.startContainer.parentNode.firstChild);
rng.setEndAfter(rng.endContainer.parentNode.lastChild);

//DEMO: verify the correct range using a temp div/alert:
var t=document.createElement("div");
t.appendChild(rng.cloneContents());
alert(t.innerHTML);
```

Comment: +1 for the idea of wrapping the range into a new div - this was useful for getting at the html