# How to keep text from being selected

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, textselection

I've googled and searched around here on SO, but haven't found an answer to this question.

I know that this can be done using `user-select:none` with CSS, but [as you can see, this is not a standard property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select), and I'm trying to find an alternative.

### NOTE: I don't care if the users can get the text. It's for the design of the site, not to keep users from copy/paste.

**I know that this CAN be done with JS.**  I do not know it it's difficult, or how to do it, but if you type `HTML` or `JS` code into the [HTMLObfuscator](http://www.htmlobfuscator.com), there is an option on the left that can disable text selection.  Is this easy to implement into certain parts of my site?  Or is it rather complicated (like in the obfuscator)?

Thank you for all your help . . .

Comment: Is it really worth all the trouble? People can just read the source and copy it from there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700000/how-to-disable-text-selection-using-jquery

Comment: No, it's for display purposes.  I don't care if they get the text.

Comment: FWIW, `user-select` might not be standard, but it is widely supported: http://caniuse.com/#feat=user-select-none

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779534/how-to-disable-text-selection-with-css-or-js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Comment: You try `onselectstart="return false"` to selection event or add `unselectable='on'` attribute to dom element.

Comment: did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6190213/586051)?

Comment: I did not find that question, @RahulDesai.  I think that that might work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Set Window selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190143/javascript-set-window-selection)

Comment: Thank you, @ariel_556.  I didn't ever think of that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS property `pointer-events: none;`.  It will keep the mouse from having any effect on the text at all, so don't use this for a button or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

CSS way:

```
element:before {
    content:'whatever';
};
```

before and after make it part of the element.

Comment: Thank you.  I can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: It's bad practice to put content in pseudo-elements like this. You suddenly have two UI content surfaces to manage. You will also wish you had not done this when it comes to translating your app into another language.